# Proving that $\frac{\sin(t\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\leq t$ for $t > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Let $t > 0$. I am trying to show that then $\frac{\sin(t\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\leq t$. I am under the assumption that this shouldn't be too hard, which leads me to believe that I must be missing something obvious as I am stuck with the proof. One observation is that you can show that $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin(t\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = t$ with L'Hopital's rule. So it would suffice to show that for no $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\frac{\sin(t\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} > t$.

Comment: With the current restrictions, your statement is not always true. For example, with $t = 0.5$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, the LHS of your inequality becomes $\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\gt 0.7$, which is obviously not $\le 0.5$. Are you possibly missing or misstated any condition(s)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan This is entirely possible! If we, for example, assume that $c\geq 1$, does the statement then hold?

Comment: FYI, I've updated my [answer](/a/4749969) to also prove that the inequality doesn't hold for *any* non-integral values of $t$, so it's only true for positive integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice problem, but the statement needs to be modified slightly:
$$
\frac{\sin t\theta}{\sin\theta} \le t \text{ for all integers } t>0.
$$
To prove this, let $\omega = e^{i\theta}$ so that $\sin \theta = (\omega - \omega^{-1})/(2i)$.  Then $$
\frac{\sin t\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{\omega^t - \omega^{-t}}{\omega - \omega^{-1}} = \omega^{t-1} + \omega^{t-3} + \cdots + \omega^{3-t} + \omega^{1-t},
$$
which one can verify by multiplying each side by $\omega - \omega^{-1}$.  Because there are $t$ terms in the expansion above, and because $|\omega^j| = 1$ for any integer $j$,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin t\theta}{\sin\theta} \right| \le |\omega^{t-1}| + |\omega^{t-3}| + \cdots + |\omega^{3-t}| + |\omega^{1-t}| = t,
$$
from which the result follows (giving a lower bound of $-t$ as well).

Answer (score 2):

Take $ t=2n\frac{\pi}{\theta}+1$, then your result is always $1$ and not $<t$.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you're trying to prove is

$$\frac{\sin(t\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} \le t \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

assumedly where $\theta$ is not an integral multiple of $\pi$. As I stated in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749702/proving-that-frac-sint-theta-sin-theta-leq-t-for-t-0#comment10078886_4749702), \eqref{eq1A} is not true with $t = 0.5$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Also, [trula's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4749760) proves \eqref{eq1A} doesn't hold for some other real $t \lt 1$. More generally, consider $t$ to be any real non-integral value. Since $\sin(x) = 0$ iff $x$ is an integral multiple of $\pi$, then $s = \sin(t\pi)$ is non-zero. However, the denominator of the LHS of \eqref{eq1A} is $0$. Thus, by taking the limit as $t \to \pi^{-}$ if $s \gt 0$, or $t \to \pi^{+}$ if $s \lt 0$, we get a limit of $+\infty$, so \eqref{eq1A} doesn't hold. This proves it's not true for any non-integral values of $t$.

However, [Jim Ferry's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4749801) shows that \eqref{eq1A} *is* true for all integers $t \gt 0$. Another way to prove this is to use induction. First, $t = 1$ in \eqref{eq1A} becomes $1 \le 1$. Next, assume \eqref{eq1A} is true for $t = k$ for some integer $k \ge 1$. Then, for $t = k + 1$, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\lvert\frac{\sin((k+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\right\rvert & = \left\lvert\frac{\sin(k\theta)\cos(\theta) + \cos(k\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\right\rvert \\
& = \left\lvert\frac{\sin(k\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} + \cos(k\theta)\right\rvert \\
& \le \left\lvert\frac{\sin(k\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\right\rvert\lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert + \lvert \cos(k\theta)\rvert \\
& \le k + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This proves that \eqref{eq1A} is also true for $t = k + 1$. Thus, by induction, it holds for all positive integers $t$.